# ld: framework not found ModelIO for architecture x86_64 when compiling my app

Tags: xcode

I was moving a small number of Cocoapods dependencies' source files into the project, and when I tried to compile my project I got the error:

```
ld: framework not found ModelIO for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What does this mean? `ModelIO` is not mentioned anywhere in my project, and my linked frameworks do not mention it either.

Comment: I tried deleting derived data, and that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error message after adding SupportKit to my Podfile.  Per the SupportKit [release notes](https://github.com/radialpoint/SupportKit/releases), they require Xcode 7 as of 2.10.1 and trying to use it while still on 6.x can produce this error: https://github.com/radialpoint/SupportKit/issues/54.

Comment: Yep yep, that was it.